# SDL Tridion Content Porter 2013 Licensing error after instalation

Tags: 2013, content-porter-2013, licensing

I have just installed SDL Tridion Content Porter 2013 using the wizard as described in the documentation. When I launch it it shows up and allows me to add the server details. However when I click "Next" after selecting the server to perform an export I get the following error *"Licensing error: License locked by another process or user"*:

[image: Content Porter Licensing error: License locked by another process or user]

Have you guys experience this before? Can you help me out identifying the cause?

I am using SDL Tridion 2013 GA, Microsoft SQL Server 2012 on a Microsoft Windows Server  2012 Standard.

**Note**: I have already restarted IIS, SDL Tridion Services and even the Server itself (twice).

**Update**: 
This is the error in the log file:

```
1/20/2014 5:39:29 PM    [Critical]  License locked by another process or user
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.ReadResponse(SoapClientMessage message, WebResponse response, Stream responseStream, Boolean asyncCall)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.InvokeAsyncCallback(IAsyncResult result)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was I was using the wrong license file for Content Porter. By applying a valid license the error went away.

Answer (score 3):

Below are my suspects,

1. It looks like you are accessing Content Porter on the server itself, may be some process are trying to access the license file
2. License file might be mapped in two places
3. Wrong license file placed but by renaming with the actual name